# Infinite product expansion of $\frac{1}{\ln(x)}$?

Tags: sequences-and-series, infinite-product

It's well-known that
\begin{array}{l}\frac1{1-x}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty x^n=\prod_{k=0}^\infty{\textstyle\sum_{i=0}^{m-1}}x^{im^k}.\\\end{array}
By using the following "theorem about product and sum":

> If $$f(x)=\prod_kf_k(x),$$then$$\frac{f'(x)}{f(x)}=\sum_k\frac{f_k'(x)}{f_k(x)}$$

we can get that
\begin{array}{l}\forall m\in\mathbb{N}\backslash\{1\}\\\frac1{1-x}=\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{f_k'(x)}{f_k(x)},\\\text{where }f_k(x)={\textstyle\sum_{i=0}^{m-1}}x^{im^k}\\for\;x\in(0;1)\\\end{array}
This identity interested me a lot. So, I was trying to find some other identities with similar construction. That intention motivated me to change the lower bound of summation from 0 to -infinity. That sum was too tough for me to express in terms of elementary functions, so I used a graphing calculator to find the function that is the closest function to this sum. After searching for roughly 2 hours I've finally found that function. It was -1/(x*ln(x)). Unfortunately, it's just a hypothesis, but who can stop me from writing it as a theorem?
\begin{array}{l}\forall m\in\mathbb{N}\backslash\{1\}\\\frac{-1}{x\ln(x)}=\sum_{k=-\infty}^\infty\frac{f_k'(x)}{f_k(x)},\\where\;f_k(x)={\textstyle\sum_{i=0}^{m-1}}x^{im^k}\\for\;x\in(0;1)\\Note\;that\;\frac{\displaystyle-1}{\displaystyle x\ln(x)}=-\frac{{\displaystyle(}\ln{\displaystyle(}{\displaystyle x}{\displaystyle)}{\displaystyle)}{\displaystyle'}}{\ln{\displaystyle(}{\displaystyle x}{\displaystyle)}}=-(\ln\vert\ln(x)\vert)'\\\end{array}
By using logarithmic rules, I rewrote the sum as a derivative of the product, but that didn't help me. That product diverges on the whole real axis. So, I was trying to find a normalization factor. Finally, using a graphing calculator, I've found it.
Here is the final hypothesis I want to prove. Have you any ideas?
\begin{array}{l}\forall m\in\mathbb{N}\backslash\{1\}:\\-\sqrt m\prod_{k=-\infty}^\infty\frac{\sum_{i=0}^{m-1}x^{im^k}}{\sqrt m}=\frac1{\ln\left(x\right)}\\for\;x\in(0;1).\\\end{array}

Comment: If you use double `$` signs, you can get display blocks for formulas, which will look much nicer than putting them in arrays, as well as being easier to type.

Comment: And don’t put text in mathjax unless absolutely necessary. No need here.

Comment: Note that in your case, $f_{k+1}(x)=f_k(x^m).$ So if $g_k=\frac{f_k’}{f_k}$ then $g_{k+1}(x)=mx^{m-1}g_k(x^m).$ Not sure if that helps any.

Comment: I doubt that $f_k(x)/\sqrt m$ converges to $1$ or $0$ as $k\to-\infty$ and $x\in (0,1),$ in which case. the last product can’t converge in a tradition.

Comment: Also, it might help to get the closed formula:$$f_k(x)=\frac{x^{m^{k+1}}-1}{x^{m^k}-1}.$$ (My original closed form was wrong.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let’s evaluate the corresponding finite product $\prod_{-N}^N$ first, and then take the limit.

First, $$\sum_{i=0}^{m-1}x^{im^k}  = \frac{1-x^{m^{k+1}}}{1-x^{m^k}}$$

This is conveniently of the form $\frac{g(k+1)}{g(k)}$, and so the product of it will telescope: $$-\sqrt m \prod_{k=-N}^N  \frac{1}{\sqrt m} \cdot \frac{1-x^{m^{k+1}}}{1-x^{m^k}} =  -\sqrt m \cdot \frac{1}{(\sqrt m)^{2N+1}} \cdot  \frac{1-x^{m^{N+1}}}{1-x^{m^{-N}}}=-\frac{1}{m^N}  \frac{1-x^{m^{N+1}}}{1-x^{m^{-N}}} $$

Taking the limit as $N\to\infty$, the numerator just tends to $1$ and this is left: $$-\frac{1}{m^N(1-x^{m^{-N}})} $$ Let $m^N = T \to \infty$. The limit of the denominator is $$ T(1-x^{1/T} ) = \frac{1-x^{1/T}}{1/T} \to \frac{-x^{1/T} \ln x \cdot -1/T^2}{ -1/T^2}\to -\ln x $$ and so the original limit is $$ \frac{1}{\ln x} $$ as required.